# Is it possible to prevent JVM from accessing specific URLs?

Tags: java, linux, security

I have a java application, which when starts, I'd like to make sure it can't access given URL ( either via DNS or IP ).

So far, JVM security policy looks like almost a perfect fit,
I can start java application with security manager and a custom policy file.

```
java -Djava.security.manager *
```

The problem is that I don't see how to create a blacklist in the policy file, I only see ability to add whitelist.

Ideally, I'd like to add

```
permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

and blacklist for example

```
permission java.net.SocketPermission "8.8.8.8:53", "connect";
```

but I don't see how to create negative permission, or blacklist in policy file

P.S.
I can't use iptables, since JVM is running in unprivileged docker container https://serverfault.com/questions/342357/block-an-ip-on-linux-without-the-use-of-iptables

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The reason may influence the solution.

Comment: Thnx for the question. The security requirement, to make sure that application is not allowed to connect to specific resource.

Comment: After a bit more digging, I got from a colleague a suggestion to try implementing custom security manager.t

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using security policy, I should change to use java security manager, and override

```
public void checkConnect(String host, int port);
public void checkConnect(String host, int port, Object context);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/smPortGuide.html

By not overriding other methods, I will allow all other methods to be allowed, and in this method, based on the `String host`, I implement small logic to approve or deny the connection.